# How can I force close windows?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I am having different windows stay open sometimes when I try to close them while in the base. As for instances, I will change out a soldier before a mission, I remove the existing soldier, and open the selection list to slot in a new rookie. The selection list stays open, and I cannot do anything to close it.

Or, I change the loadout of a soldier, and I click to view the description of an item, the item stays open on my screen, and I cannot remove it. This usually leads to a crash to desktop if I manage to launch the mission.

Is there any way to force these windows to close that I am missing?

Clicking on the icon to close them does nothing, and I have crashed more than a half dozen times due to this glitch. Usually, I can click on some of the stuff in the background screen (to activate the mission perhaps) although anything covered by the window becomes inaccessible.

Comment: PC, I assume? Those are strange bugs... My problem was the contrary - becoming lost in reading and clicking RMB to close the window. :-) What are your system specs and OS?

Comment: note that in many cases (as Orc JMR obliquely stated), the right mouse button closes or backs out of menus. Does this also fail to close windows?

Comment: Yes, PC. Windows 7, Intel Processor @ 3.2 GHZ. Nvidia GTX 590 Graphics card. I updated the drivers to the most recent release right after I got the game. Playing from a Steam DL. And yes, I try Right clicking, it does nothing.

Comment: I'm not sure how to fix the actual bug, but in terms of a hotfix, have you tried the hotkeys (Escape, or spacebar) to close windows?